# Number Generator wave cycle to graph output

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph, count

I'm looking to generate a wave form generated by a cycle of numbers that increase and then decrease on a given rate. The frequency can vary between 1 to 40 per minute and the amplitude varies between 100 and 3000. The idea is to form a breathing like pattern for "breaths per minute" (1-40) and an inhaled volume per breath (100-3000).

I'm new here and I can only find random generators. I have looked at NSTimer and UIGraphs from the Ios-Developer Tesla tutorial app.

Could anyone point me in the right direction.

Many Thanks.

Comment: I Need to generate a real-time graph plot to represent breathing. So I need a number generator to count up and down a given range.

Comment: For example 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 etc. And then for this to be represented on in the type of graph used in the ios dev tesla app.